# How can I avoid the gap between \cellcolor-colored cells created by \tabucline?

Tags: formatting, color, tabu, colortbl

I'm trying to partially separate rows from one another using `\tabucline`. The line encompasses column 3-6. Since the line's width is neither part of the upper, nor the lower row, there is going to be some space between those cells. Is there a way to avoid this? Can I somehow color the whole background including the gap?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}

\definecolor{palewhite}{RGB}{237,241,251}
\definecolor{paleblue}{RGB}{195,215,241}
\definecolor{palebluefontgrey}{RGB}{64,114,90}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{132,130,132}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{RGB}{136,174,228}
\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{gray!10} % Table row separator colour = 10% gray

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth{X[-.5,m]X[-.5,m]X[1,m]X[1,m]X[1,m]X[1,m]}
        \toprule
        \taburowcolors 1{tableheadcolor .. tableheadcolor}
        \rowfont[c]{\color{palewhite}\bfseries\sffamily}%
              &         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test 2} \tabularnewline
        \rowfont[c]{\color{palebluefontgrey}\sffamily}%
        \taburowcolors 2{paleblue .. paleblue}
        \cellcolor{tableheadcolor}  &       & Test 3 & Test 4   & Test 5 & Test 6      \tabularnewline
        \taburowcolors 1{white .. tablerowcolor}
        \tabucline{3-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{tableheadcolor}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{paleblue}} & & & & \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{tableheadcolor}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{paleblue}} & & & & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that consecutive `\tabucline` create even more gaps. This seems to work:

```
    \tabucline[tableheadcolor]{1-1}\noalign{\kern-\arrayrulewidth}
    \tabucline[paleblue]{2-2}\noalign{\kern-\arrayrulewidth}
    \tabucline{3-6}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\hhline` (`hhline` package) instead and colour a line the same as the background colour for the first two segments.